# Magic Zoom Plus issue in Safari Browser

Tags: jquery, css, magento, safari, magiczoomplus

i am facing issue on my Magento store i have used extension of Magic zoom plus. its working fine on all browsers but when i view on safari it now showing proper image size it show very small thumbnail of pic however its show accurate rollover and zoom but my main product image is very tiny. i have seen a issue in searches that it will be fixed if you using safari 4 upgrade to safari 5, i am using safari 5.1.7 but still i am having issue please help me out here is the link of my page http://www.lederhose.de/dirndlbluse-f3402.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the changes you made to the CSS.

Please apply the following CSS rules to fix your issue:

```
.MagicToolboxMainContainer { line-height:0px; }
.MagicZoomPlus { width:281px !important; }
.MagicZoomPlus img { width:100% !important; max-width:none !important; padding:0px !important; }
```

You should also update your version of Magic Zoom Plus. Your version 4.5.20 and the latest version is [4.5.30](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/).

Be aware that Magic Zoom Plus is a commercial product and you must buy a license to use it on your store. The license agreement prohibits editing the CSS in an attempt to circumnavigate the free trial text message.